# Pip only install cpu tensorflow of tensorflow 0.11

Tags: tensorflow, pip

I previously installed `tensorflow-gpu v 0.12` which worked fine, but for a code of a colleague I need `v0.11`. So I uninstalled tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu 0.12 and I tried to install v 0.11 with:

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.11.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

It successfully installs tensorflow, but not the gpu version, even though in the link above I took the gpu and not cpu version. Apparently, it doesn't matter if I choose cpu or gpu, it always only installs the cpu version.

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Thaks for @user8289596 answer the following command was useful for my case and i have successfully installed tensorflow 0.11

`pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`

Note: I am using anaconda with python 2.7 and linux

Answer (score 0):

For tensorflow versions `0.11.x` and below there isn't any `tensorflow-gpu` package in pip. The wheel corresponding to `https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.11.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl` is the correct wheel with `gpu` support. If you install this wheel via pip, it'll say `Installed tensorflow==0.11.0` but has support of CUDA-8. By downloading the individual wheels, for the `cpu` and `gpu` folder have a different md5 signature, hence they are different.

See [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10485).

Answer (score 0):

On running

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.11.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

I can successfully install `tensorflow v 0.11`.

Comment: I was able to install tensorflow v 0.11 with this answer

Comment: Does running this command really installs tensorflow 0.11? I try to execute the command but when running "import tensorflow as tf" shows error ?

```ImportError: libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory```

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS, Python 3, this worked for me:

```
export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

then install with:

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

[Source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/+/r0.11/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md) also has instructions for Python 2 and 3 on a variety of Ubuntu/Linux and MacOS configurations.